# CStheory meetup at FCRC?

Tags: discussion

I haven't been logging in the way I used to, so perhaps I missed this.  But is there any plan to do a CStheory meetup at FCRC?  I will be there, starting tomorrow night, through the ninth.  I owe Dave Clarke a Coke because he jinxed me on a comment thread, so he's the only person I have to meet, but I'd enjoy getting to know anyone else as well.

Comment: I won't be there, I'm afraid. Give the coke to one of the other CSTheory folks, the one who is most likely to be able to transfer the coke to me (via his/her network). That person then buys a coke for someone he/she knows with the instructions that eventually someone needs to buy me a coke, either directly or via the network.

Comment: I'm not going for FCRC - going to SoCG instead.

Comment: I'm here now, @ SPAA & PODC.

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be there either, though if any one is at CiE I'd be happy to meet up.

Comment: I would love to see you again Jukka. I will look for you at the keynote. It is ironic that you are one of the few site regulars I already know in real life. :)

Comment: Won't be there, but wish you a good stay. And don't forget to post questions on cstheory using FCRC tag if you hear a good question. :)

Comment: Btw, we can set a cstheory system message if you want to schedule a specific time or event for the meeting for people attending FCRC.

Comment: The SoCG community knows little of cstheory. I hope to change that a bit :)

Comment: Really?  Between David Eppstein, Sariel Har-Peled, Ken Clarkson, Gil Kalai, Peter Shor, Jack Snoeyink, Piotr Indyk, Joe O'Rourke, Riko Jacob, Mihai Patrascu, Jeff Philips, John Moeller, you, and me, I don't think we're doing that bad.